# Tailwind: Fixed footer with scrollable main?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make my footer tag stick to the bottom of the page, even when the main element has content that exceeds the viewable height, and have main be scrollable.

At the moment, if I add enough content to main it pushes footer below it which is not the desired outcome.

How can I make main not push footer below it?

Here is an example of the issue:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex flex-col h-screen justify-between">
        <main class="mb-auto h-10 bg-slate-700 text-white h-max p-4">
            <div class="habits-area space-y-4 overflow-y-auto">
                <div id="toast-default" class="flex items-center w-full p-4 text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800" role="alert">
                    <div class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-12 h-12 text-blue-500 bg-blue-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-blue-800 dark:text-blue-200">
                        <svg class="w-6 h-6" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 18 20">
                            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15.147 15.085a7.159 7.159 0 0 1-6.189 3.307A6.713 6.713 0 0 1 3.1 15.444c-2.679-4.513.287-8.737.888-9.548A4.373 4.373 0 0 0 5 1.608c1.287.953 6.445 3.218 5.537 10.5 1.5-1.122 2.706-3.01 2.853-6.14 1.433 1.049 3.993 5.395 1.757 9.117Z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <span class="sr-only">Fire icon</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-normal">
                        <p class="font-bold">Title</p>
                        Brief summary here
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-300 p-1.5 hover:bg-gray-100 inline-flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 dark:text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700" data-dismiss-target="#toast-default" aria-label="Close">
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-dial-init class="fixed right-6 bottom-6 group">
                <div id="speed-dial-menu-square" class="flex flex-col items-center hidden mb-4 space-y-2">
                    <button type="button" data-tooltip-target="tooltip-share" data-tooltip-placement="left" class="flex justify-center items-center w-[52px] h-[52px] text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600 shadow-sm dark:hover:text-white dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-gray-400">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                            <path d="M14.419 10.581a3.564 3.564 0 0 0-2.574 1.1l-4.756-2.49a3.54 3.54 0 0 0 .072-.71 3.55 3.55 0 0 0-.043-.428L11.67 6.1a3.56 3.56 0 1 0-.831-2.265c.006.143.02.286.043.428L6.33 6.218a3.573 3.573 0 1 0-.175 4.743l4.756 2.491a3.58 3.58 0 1 0 3.508-2.871Z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <span class="sr-only">Share</span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="tooltip-share" role="tooltip" class="absolute z-10 invisible inline-block w-auto px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-opacity duration-300 bg-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow-sm opacity-0 tooltip dark:bg-gray-700">
                        Share
                        <div class="tooltip-arrow" data-popper-arrow></div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" data-tooltip-target="tooltip-print" data-tooltip-placement="left" class="flex justify-center items-center w-[52px] h-[52px] text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600 shadow-sm dark:hover:text-white dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-gray-400">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                            <path d="M5 20h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-5H4v5a1 1 0 0 0 1 1Z"/>
                            <path d="M18 7H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2v-3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v3a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm-1-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v3h14Z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <span class="sr-only">Print</span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="tooltip-print" role="tooltip" class="absolute z-10 invisible inline-block w-auto px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-opacity duration-300 bg-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow-sm opacity-0 tooltip dark:bg-gray-700">
                        Print
                        <div class="tooltip-arrow" data-popper-arrow></div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" data-tooltip-target="tooltip-download" data-tooltip-placement="left" class="flex justify-center items-center w-[52px] h-[52px] text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600 shadow-sm dark:hover:text-white dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-gray-400">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                            <path d="M14.707 7.793a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 0L11 10.086V1.5a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v8.586L6.707 7.793a1 1 0 1 0-1.414 1.414l4 4a1 1 0 0 0 1.416 0l4-4a1 1 0 0 0-.002-1.414Z"/>
                            <path d="M18 12h-2.55l-2.975 2.975a3.5 3.5 0 0 1-4.95 0L4.55 12H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v4a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-4a2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm-3 5a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <span class="sr-only">Download</span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="tooltip-download" role="tooltip" class="absolute z-10 invisible inline-block w-auto px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-opacity duration-300 bg-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow-sm opacity-0 tooltip dark:bg-gray-700">
                        Download
                        <div class="tooltip-arrow" data-popper-arrow></div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" data-tooltip-target="tooltip-copy" data-tooltip-placement="left" class="flex justify-center items-center w-[52px] h-[52px] text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white shadow-sm dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-gray-400">
                         <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 18 20">
                            <path d="M5 9V4.13a2.96 2.96 0 0 0-1.293.749L.879 7.707A2.96 2.96 0 0 0 .13 9H5Zm11.066-9H9.829a2.98 2.98 0 0 0-2.122.879L7 1.584A.987.987 0 0 0 6.766 2h4.3A3.972 3.972 0 0 1 15 6v10h1.066A1.97 1.97 0 0 0 18 14V2a1.97 1.97 0 0 0-1.934-2Z"/>
                            <path d="M11.066 4H7v5a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H0v7a1.969 1.969 0 0 0 1.933 2h9.133A1.97 1.97 0 0 0 13 18V6a1.97 1.97 0 0 0-1.934-2Z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <span class="sr-only">Copy</span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="tooltip-copy" role="tooltip" class="absolute z-10 invisible inline-block w-auto px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-opacity duration-300 bg-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow-sm opacity-0 tooltip dark:bg-gray-700">
                        Copy
                        <div class="tooltip-arrow" data-popper-arrow></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" data-dial-toggle="speed-dial-menu-square" aria-controls="speed-dial-menu-square" aria-expanded="false" class="flex items-center justify-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg w-14 h-14 hover:bg-blue-800 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5 transition-transform group-hover:rotate-45" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 1v16M1 9h16"/>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Open actions menu</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="bg-slate-900">
            <div class="flex shadow-md justify-start md:justify-center rounded-lg overflow-x-scroll mx-auto py-3 px-2  md:mx-12">
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all   duration-300 uppercase"> Sun </p>
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all    duration-300"> 11 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all   duration-300 uppercase"> Sun </p>
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all    duration-300"> 11 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all   duration-300 uppercase"> Sun </p>
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all    duration-300"> 11 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all   duration-300 uppercase"> Sun </p>
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all    duration-300"> 11 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all   duration-300 uppercase"> Sun </p>
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all    duration-300"> 11 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all   duration-300 uppercase"> Sun </p>
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all    duration-300"> 11 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all   duration-300 uppercase"> Sun </p>
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all    duration-300"> 11 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all   duration-300 uppercase"> Sun </p>
                           <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all    duration-300"> 11 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all  duration-300 uppercase"> Mon </p>
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all   duration-300"> 12 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all  duration-300 uppercase"> Tue </p>
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all   duration-300"> 13</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="flex group bg-gray-600 shadow-lg light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 cursor-pointer justify-center relative content-center">
                    <span class="flex h-3 w-3 absolute -top-1 -right-1">
                        <span class="animate-ping absolute group-hover:opacity-75 opacity-0 inline-flex h-full w-full rounded-full bg-purple-400 "></span>
                        <span class="relative inline-flex rounded-full h-3 w-3 bg-purple-500"></span>
                    </span>
                    <div class="flex items-center px-3 py-2">
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <p class="text-white text-sm uppercase"> Wed </p>
                        <p class="text-white  mt-1 font-bold"> 14 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300 content-center  cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all  duration-300 uppercase"> Thu </p>
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all   duration-300"> 15 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all  duration-300 uppercase"> Fri </p>
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all   duration-300"> 16 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="flex group hover:bg-purple-100 hover:shadow-lg hover-light-shadow rounded-lg mx-1 transition-all    duration-300     cursor-pointer justify-center">
                    <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 text-sm transition-all  duration-300 uppercase"> Sat </p>
                        <p class="text-gray-500 group-hover:text-purple-900 mt-1 group-hover:font-bold transition-all   duration-300"> 17 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try following:
May be it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    main {
      flex-grow: 1;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <main class="mb-auto bg-slate-700 text-white p-4">
      <!-- Your main content here -->
      <!-- ... -->
    </main>
    <footer class="bg-slate-900">
      <!-- Your footer content here -->
      <!-- ... -->
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#html #css #tailwind